# Does Efficient Cause include Preventive Cause as a subspecies?

Tags: causation, causality

Aristotle defines 'efficient cause' (in Physics II.3, 194b24 ff) as “the primary starting point from which change or rest originates”. Does the phrase 'or rest' come to include 'preventive cause' (an entity that interferes with the outcome of a specific generative cause) as a subspecies of efficient cause?

Comment: The word 'aeremaeseoos' in Physics II.3,194b30 is the genetive of 'aeremaesis' which means 'quietude'. Your translation says 'rest'. The passage means the start or end of a change, e.g. of a movement. According to Aristotle there is an effective cause not only for the start but also for the end of a movement. - Does Aristotle speak about a 'preventive cause', in which passage?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about end of movement. A search of "preventive cause" for Aristotle did not turn up any results.  The concept of preventive cause is found in models of causal influences/mechanisms in the sciences.

Comment: Aquinas discusses how one cause can impede the action of another cause. 
[See stackexchange question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/31388/how-does-one-cause-impede-the-action-of-another-cause)